# function that generates a String in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to program a function that generates a String. The String contains only 1,0,s and S.
The numbers are binary numbers. Each number is separated through a s. And a number gives the length of the rest of the String. The capital S is the end of the String.

Examples:

```
func :: Integral a => a -> String

func 1

"1S"

func 3

"110s11s1S"

func 4

"1010s110s11s1S"
```

My problem is, that I don't know, how I can get the length of the tail (`"s1S" -> tail`, `11 -> head`) and than get the new tail.

My new code:

```
>toBinary :: Integral a => a -> String
>toBinary 0 = []
>toBinary x
>       | mod x 2 == 0 =  '0' : toBinary (div x 2) 
>       | mod x 2 == 1 =  '1' : toBinary (div x 2)

>zubinaer :: Integral a => a -> String
>zubinaer x = reverse (toBinary x)
>
>distan :: Integral a => a -> String
>distan n = if n > 0 then hilfsfunktion (n-1) "1S" else  []
>   
>       where
>           hilfsfunktion :: Integral a => a -> String -> String
>           hilfsfunktion 0 s = s
>           hilfsfunktion n s = hilfsfunktion (n-1) (zubinaer(length s + 1) ++ "s" ++ s )
```

Here my older code: http://hpaste.org/54863

Comment: yes, it is. So I thought that I could get some hints. Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: @Alexei That code is.pretty okay for a beginner. Try to use map! It really saves you work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are tackling your problem from the wrong angle. In Haskell, one often thinks of lists. Actually, a `String` is just a list of `Char`s. Try to build your function from these bricks:

- Write a function `toBinary :: Integral a => a -> [Bool]` that outputs a binary representation of its parameters. A `1` is `True` and a `0` is `False`
- You can use `map` to turn the `[Bool]` into a `String` by replacing each boolean by a character `0` or `1`.
- You can use the syntax `[1..n]` to generate a list of integers from `1` to `n`. Use `map` to generate a list of binary representation strings.
- Use `intercalate` from `Data.List` to create your string.

Comment: @Alexei You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8378281/edit) your original question and include your code. (Prepend four space to each line for syntax highlighting). You can also use a pastebin such as http://hpaste.org

Answer (score 0):

Since the tail is defined recursively (ex.: the "tail" of (f 4) is (f 3)) you can get the length of the tail by first getting the tail:

```
let the_tail = f (n-1) in
```

then calling the length function on it

```
length the_tail
```